# Difference in 3D transform in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, 3d, cross-browser

I wrote a simple web page with CSS 3D transform

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {
    border: solid thick blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 830px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateY(30deg);
    perspective: 1000px;
}
div {
    border: solid thick red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks different in Firefox and Chrome, which puzzles me.

## Screenshots

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRECj.png)

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y54ND.png)

Comment: They look the same until I add the rule `transform: rotateY(30deg);` on body